# Clavister VPN Access

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Error-Message during login: Unable to update interface address for TUN/TAP interface:

OS:Windows 7 Pro. 64-Bit Clavister-VPN-Client: 1.0.1.3 Windows 7 UAC is enabled

Connection works with administrator permission. Problem exist with a Windows 7 Standard-User. User is also member of the local network-operator-group

Question: What permissions are necessary to setup the connection with Standard-User-Permission and UAC is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with openVPN.  They gotta rework the driver for it to work under Vista/7.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/79-client/275-why-cant-i-run-openvpn-on-windows-from-a-non-admin-user-account.html